# ERROR: We can’t query your org. Make sure that you’re connected to this org and have permissions to view the object and fields

Tags: vs-code

I am getting this error when ever I try to authorize the Scratch Org, DevHub or any other sandbox.

ERROR: We can’t query your org. Make sure that you’re connected to this org and have permissions to view the object and fields.

Comment: Have you set your DevHub as default?

Comment: I get this error when trying to Authorise a Dev hub